# Why isn't my Azure SAS Token Signature matching?

Tags: php, azure, token

This is the error returned when I try to access a blob in storage:

> Code: AuthenticationFailed
>       Message: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. 
>       AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature did not match. String to sign used was xxstorageaccount rwdlac b sco 2017-08-17T21:29:24Z 2017-08-17T21:34:24Z https 2017-04-17

Here's my code:

```
$storageAccount = config('azure.storage.account');

$start = new \DateTime();     
$end = (new \DateTime())->modify('+5 minutes');
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$end = $end->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

$toSign = $storageAccount . "\n";
$toSign .= "rwdlac" . "\n";
$toSign .= "b" . "\n";
$toSign .= "sco" . "\n";
$toSign .= $start . "\n";
$toSign .= $end . "\n"; 
$toSign .= "\n";
$toSign .= "https" . "\n";
$toSign .= "2017-04-17" . "\n";

$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, $sasKeyValue, TRUE))); 
$token = "?sv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=" . $end . "&st=" . $start . "&spr=https&sig=" . $signature;

return $uri . $token;
```

Comment: What is the value for `$sasKeyValue` variable? Is it the account key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do 2 things to avoid this error.

1. Convert *start* and *end* time to GMT time via `setTimezone()` function or consider using the [gmdate function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead.
2. Decode base64 account key through `base64_decode()` function.

Please change your code like the following:

```
$storageAccount = config('azure.storage.account');

$start = (new \DateTime())->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));     
$end = (new \DateTime())->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'))->modify('+5 minutes');
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$end = $end->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

$toSign = $storageAccount . "\n";
$toSign .= "rwdlac" . "\n";
$toSign .= "b" . "\n";
$toSign .= "sco" . "\n";
$toSign .= $start . "\n";
$toSign .= $end . "\n"; 
$toSign .= "\n";
$toSign .= "https" . "\n";
$toSign .= "2017-04-17" . "\n";

$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, base64_decode($sasKeyValue), TRUE))); 
$token = "?sv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=" . $end . "&st=" . $start . "&spr=https&sig=" . $signature;

return $uri . $token;
```