# Azure - Generate SAS Token for Blob from PHP

Tags: php, azure

I have created a SAS Token from within the portal & all works fine, i can access Private blobs.

I am trying to create new SAS Tokens on the fly using this function:

```
function generateSasToken($uri, $sasKeyName, $sasKeyValue) 
{ 
    $targetUri = strtolower(rawurlencode(strtolower($uri))); 
    $expires = time();     
    $expiresInMins = 60; 
    $week = 60*60*24*7;
    $expires = $expires + $week; 
    $toSign = $targetUri . "\n" . $expires; 
    $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',             
    $toSign, $sasKeyValue, TRUE))); 

    $token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" . $targetUri . "&sig=" . $signature . "&se=" . $expires .         "&skn=" . $sasKeyName; 
    return $token; 
}
```

This does generate a SAS Token, however in a slightly different format to the account wide one generated from the portal.

When trying to use the Token i recieve the error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:1d65690e-e01e-00a6-3d3f-b505c1000000 Time:2018-03-06T11:40:20.5662128Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

The account wide SAS which works correctly has this format:

```
?sv=2017-07-29&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=2019-03-03T04:26:37Z&st=2018-03-02T20:26:37Z&spr=https&sig=LjxZDst%2F1Ec745%2BMpZ8PueQErDCySr%2BQLRV1UKBtEGE%3D
```

The SAS Token generated by the function, which fails, has this format:

```
SharedAccessSignature
sr=<URL>%2fnewteamofficialfc%2fsummarydata.csv&sig=8cURAqmkXFVbq7CYyfk3BsXZJ0dJbHwNhiwJ1jL8jMA%3D&se=1520941694&skn=key2
```

Comment: Constructing a `Service SAS` is very well documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-a-service-sas. Looking at your code, I see that you're not following the instructions outlined there.

Answer (score 5):

Using the most recent version of the PHP API (August 2020), you can use the following class to generate the SAS. All you'll need is your:

- account name
- account key
- container name
- blob name

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Resources;

$sas_helper = new MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper($_ENV['azure_account_name'], $_ENV['azure_account_key']);
$sas = $sas_helper->generateBlobServiceSharedAccessSignatureToken(
    Resources::RESOURCE_TYPE_BLOB,              # Resource name to generate the canonicalized resource. It can be Resources::RESOURCE_TYPE_BLOB or Resources::RESOURCE_TYPE_CONTAINER
    "{$container}/{$blob}",                     # The name of the resource, including the path of the resource. It should be {container}/{blob}: for blobs.
    "r",                                        # Signed permissions.
    (new \DateTime())->modify('+10 minute'),    # Signed expiry
    (new \DateTime())->modify('-5 minute'),     # Signed start
    '',                                         # Signed IP, the range of IP addresses from which a request will be accepted, eg. "168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70"
    'https',                                    # Signed protocol, should always be https
);
echo "https://{$_ENV['azure_account_name']}.blob.core.windows.net/{$container}/{$blob}?{$sas}";
```

Replace the `$_ENV` variables with your preferred method of accessing API keys.

To read more about what the heck is going up above, have a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#service-sas-example

Comment: Thanks for this. If you're using this code snippet, you'll want to add the namespace for Resources at the top: `use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Resources;`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this blog post:

[Generating Shared access signature(SAS) on Azure Blob using PHP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/05/12/generating-shared-access-signaturesas-on-azure-blob-using-php/)

See also:

- [Microsoft Azure and SAS for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472643/microsoft-azure-and-sas-for-php)
- [Why isn't my Azure SAS Token Signature matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745287/why-isnt-my-azure-sas-token-signature-matching/45750919#45750919)
- [SAS Azure Signature did not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044373/sas-azure-signature-did-not-match/41052480#41052480)